# How to run John Ripper attack to p12 password (educative pruposes)?

Tags: security, encryption, openssl, key, public-key-encryption

I want to crack the p12 password to extract the public key using openssl

```
penssl pkcs12 -in yourP12File.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out publicCert.pem
```

After putting this command it ask me the password. I want to know how the `john` command has to be writed to try to break the password.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the `john` distribution/package are many tools (ending with suffix `2john`) used to convert the encrypted file to "`john` format". In Your case:

```
pfx2john yourP12File.pfx  |john /dev/stdin
```

Answer (score 1):

Complementing Jurgen's response, for Mac Osx you can install through:

```
brew install john-jumbo
```

Then get hashes file [here](https://www.tunnelsup.com/getting-started-cracking-password-hashes/) (`cmiyc_2012_password_hash_files`) and load it (this will take long). Example:

```
./john hashes-3.des.txt
```

See more examples in [this pdf](https://countuponsecurity.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/jtr-cheat-sheet.pdf). Finally, find where `pfx2john.py` is and run it. Example

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/john-jumbo/1.9.0/share/john/
pfx2john.py ~/mycertificate.pfx | john /dev/stdin
```

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't make john work, so I rigged up this:

```
cat rockyou.txt| 
while read p; do 
    echo trying $p; 
    openssl pkcs12 -in "xyz.p12"  -passin "pass:$p"; 
    RC=$?; if [ $RC -eq 0 ]; then 
break; fi ; done
```