# Decrypt keystore/truststore files with the password

Tags: java, encryption, keystore

I am trying to deploy a `kafka-ui` [application](https://github.com/tchiotludo/akhq).

The logs indicate that:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$FileBasedStore.load(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:372)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

I am pretty sure I have set the correct password, so my question is (assuming I have access to all necessary files) how can I run a decryption of the keystore/clientstore files?

Comment: To decrypt it you must supply the correct password. What else is there to say?

Comment: Do check if you have a non-ASCII character in the password. If you are using openssl then it can handle that, keypass can't.

Comment: [Run John the Ripper to recover password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53547386/238704).

Comment: Was this PKCS12 created using OpenSSL 3.0.x, and are you running on Java below 11.0.12 or an even numbered update of 8? If so dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72412346/java-keytool-importing-pkcs12-to-jks-getting-error-keystore-password-was-inc .